# Active sheet name change in sequence

Tags: excel, rename, spreadsheet, vba

I've got a workbook with two spreadsheets named "WT-1" and "CL-1" (it could be more of them with diff. names).
When i.e. "WT-1" is active, I would like to be able to (by using a button with macro assigned to it) copy this current (active) spreadsheet and rename it in sequence like WT-2, WT-3, WT-4 etc .

I guess change needs to apply only to spreadsheets who's name contains "WT-" as the name change should be addressed to the new sheet only. All other existing worksheets should not be touched. here it is - Pls help :) It changes name of one new spreadsheet. If there is more than just 1 worksheet in my workbook, it doesn't work.

```
Sub changeWSname()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim shtName As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("wslist")
        Set Rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)
        shtName = Application.Transpose(Rng)
        i = LBound(shtName)
End With

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If Left(Trim(ws.Name), 3) = "WT-" Then
        ws.Name = shtName(i)
        i = i + 1
      End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Macro is suppose just to change the name of a new and freshly copied spreadsheet. So if I copy WT-2 and create new sheet named WT-2(2) and run macro - it will work and change new sheet name to WT-1 (being first name in the range on 'wslist') . That seems to be OK. But, if I have any other spreadsheet in my workbook (except active sheet and already copied new sheet) it doesn't work and gives me an error 1004 - "Cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic"
When I click on de-bag, this I found highlighted: ws.Name = shtName(i)

Comment: Because this is not a free code writing service please [edit] your question and add the code you already tried. Explain what your code actually does, what it should do instead, where you got stuck or where you got errors and which.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that - I am quite new on this (or any) forum and this is my first thread. Here is a macro I was trying to use:

Comment: Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name Like "WT-*" Then
Sheets("wslist").UsedRange.Copy
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
End If
Next ws

Worksheets("addresses").Select
End Sub

Comment: I did - hope this is OK now?

Comment: Now you just need to explain what is wrong with that code? Were do you get any errors? What does it do instead of what you expect? "*it doesn't work.*" is no description. And a list of which sheet names you have (before you run the macro, and what you expect after you run it) would be good to see the difference. Also a screenshot of sheet `wslist` would be good.

Comment: Macro is suppose just to change the name of a new and freshly copied spreadsheet. So if I copy WT-2 and create new sheet named WT-2(2) and run macro - it will work and change new sheet name to WT-1 (being first name in the range on 'wslist') . That seems to be OK. But, if I have any other spreadsheet in my workbook (except active sheet and already copied new sheet) it doesn't work and gives me an error 1004 - "Cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic".

Comment: a range on my 'wslist' is from A1 to A40 and names are: WT-1 to WT-40

Comment: when I click on de-bag, this I found highlighted: ws.Name = shtName(i)

Comment: @Miles Please edit your question to include these explanations, so that new readers easily can get a grasp of your problem without reading a long thread of comments. :)

Comment: Your code works for me with two sheets called WT-1 and WT-2 and with 1 in A1 and 2 in A2 in wsList I get sheets renamed as 1 and 2.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av_nIf8pouuht104mB9Ay4_Q_zC9

Comment: but what happens with 1 item in column A? Then there is no array and a type mismatch error when trying to set i

Comment: Thanks QAHarr - pls have a look I just updated my question with better explanation what the problem is .. Can you help please?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Has solved the main issue. There are just some assumptions also made about length of what is in column A and how that relates to the number of sheets with WT- in their name. I think i saw two problems areas one of which is if you have a single cell range that you try to get the ubound on > Type mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is if you have the situation with following sheets

- `WT-1`
- `WT-1 (2)`
- `WT-2`

Your code tries to rename `WT-1 (2)` into `WT-2` but that already exists.

So a possibility was you would need to rename these to something else first like

- `WT-1`
- `#WT-2`
- `#WT-3`

and then remove the `#` in another loop.

This way you prevent renaming into a name that already exists.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub changeWSname()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shtName As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("wslist")
        Set Rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)
        shtName = Application.Transpose(Rng)
        i = LBound(shtName)
    End With
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left$(Trim(ws.Name), 3) = "WT-" Then
            'test if we run out of sheet names
            If i > UBound(shtName) Then
                MsgBox "Running out of sheet names … aborting"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            ws.Name = "#" & shtName(i) 'add a # to all new sheet names
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next ws

    'remove the # from the sheet nam
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left$(Trim(ws.Name), 1) = "#" Then
            ws.Name = Right$(ws.Name, Len(ws.Name) - 1)
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

As QHarr pointed out it's probably a good idea to test if you are running out of sheet names.

Comment: Also,  needs test that array is going into i =  UBound(shtName)

Comment: Spot on ... Thank you sooooo much!!! Wonderful ! Sorry about the trouble as I was not quite aware how to use this site :(

Comment: Peh, this is absolutely great solution and it works well. @QHarr thank you as well. You are great guys!